# Spark Java - Why Tuple2 can not be argument of function in map?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am new to Spark. I have written the following Java code

```
JavaPairRDD<Detection, Detection> allCombinations = currentLevelNodes.cartesian(nextLevelNodes);

allCombinations.map(new Function<Tuple2<Detection, Detection>, Segment>(){
  public Segment call(Tuple2<Detection, Detection> combination){
     Segment segment = new Segment();
     Detection a = combination._1();
     Detection b = combination._2();
     segment.distance = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((a.x)-(b.x), 2) + Math.pow((a.y)-(b.y), 2) );

     return segment;
  }
});
```

The IDE(Eclipse Neon) shows up the following message

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The method map(Function<Tuple2<Detection,Detection>,R>) in the type 
 AbstractJavaRDDLike<Tuple2<Detection,Detection>,JavaPairRDD<Detection,Detection>> is not applicable for the arguments (new 
 Function<Tuple2<Detection,Detection>,Segment>(){})
- The type new Function<Tuple2<Detection,Detection>,Segment>(){} must implement the inherited abstract method 
 Function<Tuple2<Detection,Detection>,Segment>.apply(Tuple2<Detection,Detection>)
```

How do I solve this problem ?

Comment: Error says you're implementing call() but you should implement apply() instead. Using lambda will make your life easier

Comment: also, are you sure you can use a Tuple2 instead of a JavaPairRDD as argument of the mapping function?

Comment: I try to modify the function name "call" to "apply", but it still show up the first line message.

Comment: I transform the JavaPairRDD to JavaRDD<Tuple2<Detection, Detection>> and use map function, the situation also exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Lambda Expressions and solved this problem.

This my sample code

```
JavaPairRDD<Detection,Detection> allCombinations = currentLevelNodes.cartesian(nextLevelNodes);

JavaRDD<Segment> segmentRDD = allCombinations.map(tuple -> new Segment(tuple._1, tuple._2));
```

and I add the constructor

```
public Segment(Detection a, Detection b){
  this.distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a.x-b.x, 2)+Math.pow(a.y-b.y, 2));
}
```

and it's works.

Comment: hope this answer can help somebody like me